# Snappy Laravel PDF export not loading CSS

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-snappy

I'm trying to export a page in PDF format with Snappy Laravel. I have the page with all the CSS and it works great and looks great, but when I try to export it, my page is downloaded in pdf format but without any CSS. Here is the code and what I have already tried:

**Controller:**

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.userReport');
$pdf->setOption('enable-javascript', true);
$pdf->download('myFileName.pdf');
```

**Head:**

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**PS:** I tried to put the absolute path to the CSS file, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Change this in your blade to  `<link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>`

to `<link href="{{ public_path('css/pdf.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

this solve the problem form my side.

Comment: It is not working for me, could you please help me, [I posted my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65944326/1883256).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have latest snappy and wkhtmltopdf.

Here is my Snappy config:

```
'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => env('WKHTML_PDF_BINARY', '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [
        'enable-local-file-access' => true,
        'keep-relative-links' => true,
    ],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

Here is my Blade file for including file:

```
<link href="{{ public_path('css/pdf.css', ) }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Snappy on Lumen (almost same that Laravel) using Docker. I had to try several things to get it to finally work for me.

In my case, in the file `config/snappy.php` I put the following code:

```
'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => env('WKHTML_PDF_BINARY', '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [
        'enable-local-file-access' => true,
        'keep-relative-links' => true,
    ],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

Setting the `enable-local-files-access` variable is the key to getting CSS/JS/IMG files to be read and loaded correctly. [(wkhtmltopdf docs)](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)

Then to define the path of the files (CSS/JS/IMG) in the HTML file, I used the method `file:///var/www/html/public/<file-path>` (in my case the files are in the public folder), for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///var/www/html/public/html/css/icons/app.css" type="text/css"/>

<script src="file:///var/www/html/public/html/js/js_file.js"></script>

<img src="file:///var/www/html/public/html/css/img/icon.png"/>
```

It works fine for me without any problem. You can tailor the route to make it work for you.

Hope it helps you (despite the years) and helps another poor programmer who has to deal with Snappy.